# how long would memtest86 take to run in these cases. and would it ever go on indefinitely?

Tags: memtest86+

How long would memtest86 take on a P4 2GHz 512MB RAM?

What about a Pentium M 1GHz  512MB RAM?

I recently tried it on the latter, and saw it had 2 progress bars at the top one said "pass" and goes from 0% to 100%, and the one below it says Test # and runs through a number of tests, each one going from 0% to 100%   I think that's how it was. So one pass included a number of tests completing.

I looked at it after during 2 hours,  at one point I saw the pass progress bar had gone through and gone to the start with another pass.  After 2 hours,  it said  4 passes 0 errors.  I saw an option to press escape to exit.  But it was continuing. Eventually I just exitted.

Would it go on indefinitely? Just continuously doing more and more passes?

Is it common for people to just do one pass? is that recommended?
if not, how many are recommended?

btw, what is the difference between memtest86 and memtest86+?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> Would it go on indefinitely? Just continuously doing more and more passes?

I believe so.

> Is it common for people to just do one pass

It's common to run it for multiple passes, recommended is to run it for atleast 8 hours. It's not uncommon to see it run for 12+ hours

> btw, what is the difference between memtest86 and memtest86+?

memtest86+ is a port of memtest86, supports more recent processors,chipsets and higher capacity RAM.

Comment: what happens if you run memtest86 on recent processors, chipsets and on higher capacity ram?

Comment: It wouldn't run. It might have been fixed by now @barlop