# Motherboard issue?

Tags: memory, motherboard

I have a system that will partially start. It gets up to about 1GB of memory, then completely freezes. It detects all the memory I put in, whether it is 8 or 16GB. I have used completely different sticks, could this be a motherboard issue? I have tried using several different OS'es to make sure this is not the issue. The system posts and will start Windows and Linux, but freezes at what I would expect to be about the 1GB mark.
Thanks in advance

Comment: I believe this is the most appropriate of all the sites to ask on, but if not I apologize.

Comment: try safe mode. try event viewer. try memtest86+ http://superuser.com/questions/189981/how-long-would-memtest86-take-to-run-in-these-cases-and-would-it-ever-go-on-ind

Comment: We need more information.  If the system is not even completing POST, it means you have a hardware problem, not a software problem.

Comment: you need to explsin what you mean by ". It gets up to about 1GB of memory, then completely freezes"  Do you mean you check in 'task manager' within the OS.  You say you tried different OSs and if you are making even a grain of sense then you mean you are getting past POST. Are you?

Comment: I would like to clarify that the motherboard gets past post, and will start Windows or Linux until what I expect to be about the 1GB mark.

Comment: Can you look very carefully at memory slots? Look for any kind of tiny conductive junk and damaged contacts.

Comment: Have you tried to log CPU and GPU temperature? Maybe it is not about memory, maybe it is about heat?

Comment: "and will start Windows or Linux until what I expect to be about the 1GB mark."  You didn't say this in the question, you should, claim the question and edit it.  But it also does not make sense.

Comment: @Ramhound He did say in his question about the 1GB and he did say in his question he has tried different OSs (obviously more like windows and linux, not minix and Os2 warp - not that it necessarily even matters which - as he says that whichever OS he tried he has this issue). And his computer getting past POST is something one could gather from his question if giving him the assumption of some intelligence as I did - since he said in his question that he tried different OSs and he's talking about his computer freezing. So it was clear enough for me to understand.

Comment: @Ramhound what is it about his question that you think doesn't make sense? It is possible that he opens task manager or equivalent, and sees memory usage grow to 1GB, and then his system freezes. I've not seen that behavior before but it's not impossible.

Comment: @barlop - Its not specific enough.  If you are guessing at what it actually means ( and I know your skills are beyond mine ) doesn't that mean the statement is simply not clear?  I have seen tons of machines in the past do memory checks part more of a POST than the operating system itself.

Comment: @Ramhound I've seen it too-counting the memory,though combined with detection.I think u questioning whether he was getting past POST was a reasonable question.But he'd b a bit silly if he was trying different operating systems on a system stuck during POST.(even the term freezing tends to be used with OSs rather than the BIOS so he didn't use the term badly) I'll grant u that he couldve been better.eg Stating that he was looking at processes in his OS's "task manager"seeing the 1GB usage issue(without the reader having to derive it).And he could've provided a screenshot of the bizarre behavior

Comment: I was just trying to get more information.  Until I get that information.  Its not clear, at least in my eyes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Considering all the information gathered from the numerous comments.  The ideal solution is that your data paths along your mother board arent working like they are supposed to.  These data paths I speak allow hardware to "talk" to one another.  So if you see those gold lines on your mother board, you'll notice they go from one end to another.  Since you stated that since this occurs with your CD Rom as well, RAM would not be a factor if what you stated is that you changed the ram around and your BIOS is i fact detecting the amount of RAM you install.

Look on your MoBo and find the gold lines and trace them all!  If you notice bits missing, then take it to a repair store and get it fixed.

Comment: *"gold lines"* -- They are copper metal called "traces".

Comment: what kind of repair store fixes motherboards? are you in india?

Comment: It depends on the store @barlop

Comment: @Virusboy can you give an example of one you're familiar with?

Comment: You write "Since you stated that since this occurs with your CD Rom as well, RAM would not be a factor if what you stated is that you changed the ram around and your BIOS is i fact detecting the amount of RAM you install." <-- Why does CDROM matter? Whether he loads an OS via CD or HDD  RAM is going to be used.  The thing that I suppose suggests it's not RAM is him saying in his q that he used completely different sticks - well spotted there. But whether OS or OS installation starts from CD has not much to do with showing whether RAM is at fault. It just shows it's not the hard drive

Comment: No I cannot give one, I tend to repair those myself.
Here let me explain it better than.
Since RAM is the main item used in a PC, the first thing thought of is well RAM, so When RAM isnt a culprit its time troubleshoot.  Thats where you use trial and error to find the problem maker.  Since we already knew the HDD kept freezing, we had to find if the CDROM would work at all.  Since it does, it therefore crosses out that it is neither the CDROM the HDD or RAM.  So with our brilliant use of intelligent deduction, we can logically deduce the Motherboard is in fact to blame.  Still confused?

Comment: I am sorry.  There are hundreds perhaps thousands of traces on a modern motherboard.  Some are cannot even be seen because they are internal traces.  **A modern repair shop isn't going to be able to repair a problem like this.**

Answer (score -1):

I have seen this issue before. Some motherboard makes that have UEFI built in become ruined when you install linux of any bread onto it. Linux has a habbit of making full use of any resources that are available to it. Some UEFI chips tend to freak out when more than 50% of its resources are used up. It's not your ram that's messing things up, it's your UEFI's incompatibility with linux.
Unfortunetly, this issue isn't recognized by POST. The only thing you can do now is, hope your warranty is still valid and call them and wrench on them for a new one because they didn't let you add what ever you want on it. It's extremely important to google OS compatibility to any motherboard with UEFI on it as this will cause issues. ALWAYS GOOGLE WHAT YOU'RE DOING EVEN IF YOU KNOW WHAT YOU'RE DOING

Comment: I don't think this is the issue because I had Linux and Windows installed together for a while, but I had installed Windows updates and was restating the last time it worked. And Windows gets 10 seconds into it's loading screen, and Linux does competely start, but then the system freezes.

Comment: I think using all memory is not bad habbit. It is just "diffrent approach" to memory management.

Comment: The system freezes after Linux os completely loaded and after Windows has started loading.

Comment: Describe how it freezes. Does it demonstrate any graphical ticks. How does it handle liveCD's?

Comment: The system good through the bios, then asks Windows or ubuntu. I chose Windows, and Windows begins loading. After about ten seconds, the hard drive stops. If I loaded from the install CD, the same process happens.

Comment: Bottom line is, your UEFI has puckered up and kissed the asphalt.